# Vue2-datepicker separating array output to v-models

Tags: vuejs2, datepicker, vue-component

I'm new to vuejs and Expressjs. I have been using vue2-datepicker with the range prop for getting a range of dates selected by the user for a reservation system where there is a CheckIn and CheckOut Date. And what vue2-datepicker outputs is an array.

Here is the datepicker:

```
<date-picker v-model="time1" valueType="format" range></date-picker>
```

What it outputs:

> [ "2020-01-02", "2020-01-11" ]

While I do know how to use it for the front-end:

```
<h3>Available Rooms for the date: {{ this.time1[0] }} to {{ this.time1[1] }}</h3>
```

The problem is how I can separate the array output to put the first date selected to CheckInDate and CheckOutDate for the second date selected to put in to my database.

Maybe something like this:

```
data(){
            return{
                time1:'',
                ReserveDateForm:{
                CheckInDate:this.time1[0],
                CheckOutDate:this.time1[1]
                },
            }
        },
```

Tried it like that at first, which kinda broke the app

Comment: Create a setter and getter for the v-model, and within the setter and getter you can split/combine the array elements.

Comment: Tried to search what that is, I kinda got the gist of it, but I don't know how I can implement it here

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to solve this with computed properties and watchers, but this seems to be not working all the time because of the nested structure of `time1`. However you could easily seperate the outputs and update them accordingly like this

```
<date-picker v-model="time1" @input="updateTime" valueType="format" range></date-picker>
```

```
data() {
    return{
        time1:"",
        ReserveDateForm:{
            CheckInDate: "",
            CheckOutDate: ""
    },
},
methods: {
    updateTime(time) {
        this.ReserveDateForm = {
            CheckInDate: time[0],
            CheckInDate: time[1]
        }
    }
}
```